# пишу кликер на Pygame, но есть проблемы!

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Я пишу кликер, но у меня не отображается количество денег на дисплэе!

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()

RES = WIGHT, HEIGHT = 495, 880

sc = pg.display.set_mode(RES)


FPS = 30
clock = pg.time.Clock()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 235)


money = 1
click = 1

font = pg.font.SysFont('Calibri', 35)

while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            quit()
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            position = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            x, y = position

            if 97.5 <= x <= 397.5 and 280 <= y <= 580:
                money += click

    sc.fill(BLACK)
    pg.draw.rect(sc, RED, (97.5, 280, 300, 300), 2)
    moneytext = font.render('Money: ' + str(money), WHITE, 5)
    sc.blit(moneytext, (200, 20))

    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо в метод `font.render` передать также параметр `antialias`, ибо он имеет сигнатуру:

```py
def render(
    self,
    text: Union[str, bytes],
    antialias: bool,
    color: _ColorValue,
    background: Optional[_ColorValue] = None,
) -> Surface: ...
```

Таким образом, достаточно `font.render('Money: ' + str(money), WHITE, 5)` поменять на `font.render('Money: ' + str(money), True, WHITE, 5)`

Comment: Вы сначала приняли ответ, а потом отказались. Что-то работает не так?